# JS can't call function when content is dynamically added

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok, I have this HTML:

```
<td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="addImage('<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_banner_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
```

On click I call JS function `addImage`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addImage(language_id) {
html = '<td class="text-left"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="date-ended"><?php echo 'Date Started' ?></label><div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1"><input name="background_images_date_ended" type="text" id="date-ended" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div></div></div></td>';

$('#images' + language_id + ' tbody').append(html);
</script>
```

After that I want to call function on this div `<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">`

**This function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

But this div is dynamically added and I don't know, but the function is not running.

Comment: Reinitialize datetimepicker after adding dynamically

Comment: Name the function you want to call and call it at the end of your addImage function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you just dont init the datetimepicker at the bottom of the addImage function, or call another function from there?

```
function addImage(language_id) {
        html = '  <td class="text-left"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="date-ended"><?php echo 'Date Started' ?></label><div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1"><input name="background_images_date_ended" type="text" id="date-ended" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div></div></div></td>';

$('#images' + language_id + ' tbody').append(html);
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
}
```

or

```
function addImage(language_id) {
  ....
  initDatepicker();
}

function initDatepicker () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For elements dynamically added, you must use event handlers like this:

```
someElement.addEventListener( "click", function() { 
       //some code to run on click
});
```

This should work for you then